# Kubernetes config version error - your configuration file uses an old API spec: "kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha1"

Tags: kubernetes

I'm following this [tutorial](https://kubecloud.io/setting-up-a-kubernetes-1-11-raspberry-pi-cluster-using-kubeadm-952bbda329c8) to create a Raspberry Pi Kubernetes cluster. This is what my config looks like:

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: MasterConfiguration
controllerManagerExtraArgs:
  pod-eviction-timeout: 10s
  node-monitor-grace-period: 10s
```

The problem is, when I run `sudo kubeadm init --config kubeadm_conf.yaml` I get the following error:

```
your configuration file uses an old API spec: "kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha1". Please use kubeadm v1.11 instead and run 'kubeadm config migrate --old-config old.yaml --new-config new.yaml', which will write the new, similar spec using a newer API version.
```

I've tried looking [here](https://linuxacademy.com/community/posts/show/topic/31110-your-configuration-file-uses-an-old-api-spec-kubeadmk8siov1) for help, but nothing's worked. Help is appreciated.

If I use v1beta1"

```
>W0505 13:10:25.319213   15824 strict.go:47] unknown configuration schema.GroupVersionKind{Group:"kubeadm.k8s.io", Version:"v1beta1", Kind:"MasterConfiguration"}                                                                                                                                    for scheme definitions in "k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/apis/kubeadm/scheme/scheme.go:31" and "k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/componentconfigs/scheme.go:28"
[config] WARNING: Ignored YAML document with GroupVersionKind kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta1, Kind=MasterConfiguration
no InitConfiguration or ClusterConfiguration kind was found in the YAML file
```

Comment: tutorial is working on kubernetes version 1.9. but latest version is 1.14. Seems like you need to upgrade tools accordingly. BTW, did you tried marking it vibeta1 ?

Comment: @PrateekJain I haven't tried that. I've searched for a way to update, but haven't found one yet. Any help?

Comment: @PrateekJain I have tried v1beta1 though if that's what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Verify versions:

```
    kubeadm version
    kubeadm config view
```

2. Generate default settings for your init command to see your settings (should be modified):

```
    kubeadm init --config defaults
```

3. Did you try the solution provided by the output?

```
     kubeadm config migrate --old-config old.yaml --new-config new.yaml
```

You can find tutorial about [kubeadm init --config](https://medium.com/@kosta709/kubernetes-by-kubeadm-config-yamls-94e2ee11244)

In addition if you are using older version please take a look for [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/#config-file)

> It is recommended that you migrate your old v1alpha3 configuration to v1beta1 using the kubeadm config migrate command, because v1alpha3 will be removed in Kubernetes 1.15.
>   For more details on each field in the v1beta1 configuration you can navigate to our [API reference pages](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/apis/kubeadm/v1beta1)

Migration from old kubeadm config versions:

> kubeadm v1.11 should be used to migrate v1alpha1 to v1alpha2; kubeadm v1.12 should be used to translate v1alpha2 to v1alpha3)

Fo the second issue `no InitConfiguration or ClusterConfiguration kind was found in the YAML file` there is also answer in docs:

> When executing kubeadm init with the --config option, the following configuration types could be used: InitConfiguration, ClusterConfiguration, KubeProxyConfiguration, KubeletConfiguration, but only one between InitConfiguration and ClusterConfiguration is mandatory.

Comment: Im on windows 10 trying to get minikube running and have hit this error i cant seam to find kubadm any idea where it might be?

Answer (score 0):

what is the kubernetes version are you using?

try below

apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha2

OR

apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha3